# Using Meteor with input of checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Hello I have having a problem with my checkbox's staying checked when I check them. So what I want to be able to do is check and uncheck as I click the box. But once I check it it is stuck with a check and I can no longer do anything to it. Here is the relevant code!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ResolutionSingle extends Component {

  toggleChecked() {
    Meteor.call('toggleResolution', this.props.resolution._id, this.props.resolution.copmlete);
  }

  deleteResolution() {
    Meteor.call('deleteResolution', this.props.resolution._id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox"
               readOnly={true}
               checked={this.props.resolution.complete}
               onClick={this.toggleChecked.bind(this)} />
        {this.props.resolution.text}
        <button className="btn-cancel"
          onClick={this.deleteResolution.bind(this)}>
          &times;
        </button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Here are the methods

```
Meteor.methods({
  addResolution(resolution) {
    Resolutions.insert({
      text: resolution,
      complete: false,
      createAt: new Date()
    });
  },
  toggleResolution(id, status) {
    Resolutions.update(id, {
      $set: {complete: !status}
    });
  },
  deleteResolution(id) {
    Resolutions.remove(id);
  }
});
```

Here is the main wrapper

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

import ResolutionsForm from './ResolutionsForm.jsx';
import ResolutionSingle from './ResolutionSingle.jsx';


Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection("resolutions");

export default class ResolutionsWrapper extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state =  {
      subscription: {
        resolutions: Meteor.subscribe("allResolutions")
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.subscription.resolutions.stop();
  }

  resolutions() {
    return Resolutions.find().fetch();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My Resolutions</h1>
        <ResolutionsForm />
        <ul className="resolutions">
          {this.resolutions().map( (resolution)=>{
            return <ResolutionSingle key={resolution._id} resolution={resolution} />
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this looks ok. Please include code where props get passed to `ResolutionSingle`.

Comment: I added the main wrapper which uses the ResolutionSingle! I am pretty sure I have the same code as the tut I am watching too. He does this on linux and I do it on windows not that it should make a difference here. My checks just stay checked when I check them. Or the value stays true instead of toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

```
Meteor.call('toggleResolution', this.props.resolution._id, this.props.resolution.copmlete);
```

It should be `complete` instead of `copmlete`. In order to avoid errors like that in the future, you can use [check](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/check) functions in your Meteor methods.

Comment: You are a savior! And awesome I will keep that in mind!